# Class diagram of an Hotel Management System

Tags: class-diagram

I am given the following system description :

> Consider a hotel
> management system to manage a group of 5-stars hotels. If this system is modelled using OOP methodology, and the classes are identified as Hotel, Trip, Room, VIP Room, Regular Room, Suite, Customer, Payment, Cash_Payment, Credit_Debit_Payment, Reservation.

Now I need to draw its UML class diagram, here is my solution :
[image]

I have related the customer class indirectly with the Hotel using the reservation class which is related to the Room class and Trip class and both of them are related to the Hotel class is this a valid solution ?. Also, did I miss any composition or Aggregation relationships? Because I am really confused in the relationship between reservation and payment classes because we can say that payment is part of reservation so it may be right that this relationship is a composition one ? Also , does the relationship between reservation and room is  a " part of " relationship also because if we delete the room class we should delete the reservation class?  Finally, are these multiplicities right?   I am just participating in some problems for class diagrams to understand it, so please help me.

Comment: Guys why I am not having an answer to this question ? Is there is something unclear ? Please let me know and I will edit the question .